# Initializing new Entities causes FK exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, xunit

I have an integration test exhibiting some strange behavior and I think it's because I'm misunderstanding something about EF Core.

The code below is just the "Arrange" portion of the test, but it's causing my problems. It should do the following:

1. Set up a "Carrier" `Contact` which contains a reference to an existing `ContactType` record in the database (basically, an Enum).
2. Set up a "Venor" `Contact` which contains a reference to an existing `ContactType` in the database (basically, an Enum).3. Save changes to persist.

#### Broken Example

```cs
[Fact]
public void StackOverflow_BrokenExample()
{
    // Arrange
    var carrierContactType = Context.ContactTypes.FirstOrDefault(ct => ct.Id == ContactTypeEnum.Carrier);
    var carrierContact = new Contact
    {
        Name = "Test Carrier Contact",
        Address1 = "456 Some Street",
        IsActive = true,
        ContactTypes = new List<ContactType>()
        {
            carrierContactType,
        },
    };
    Context.Contacts.Add(carrierContact);

    var vendorContactType = Context.ContactTypes.FirstOrDefault(ct => ct.Id == ContactTypeEnum.Vendor);
    var vendorContact = new Contact()
    {
        Name = "Test Vendor Contact",
        Address1 = "123 Another Street",
        IsActive = true,
        ContactTypes = new List<ContactType>()
        {
            vendorContactType,
        },
    };
    Context.Contacts.Add(vendorContact);

    Context.SaveChanges();
}
```

> The MERGE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_ContactTypeXrefs_Contacts_ContactId". The conflict occurred in database "VF_BillOfLading", table "dbo.Contacts", column 'Id'.

The SQL generated includes this:

```
dbug: 9/20/2023 12:15:31.172 CoreEventId.ForeignKeyChangeDetected[10803] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking) 
      The foreign key property 'Contact.Id' was detected as changed from '-2147482647' to '1' for entity with key '{Id: 1}'.
dbug: 9/20/2023 12:15:31.179 CoreEventId.ForeignKeyChangeDetected[10803] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking) 
      The foreign key property 'Contact.Id' was detected as changed from '-2147482646' to '2' for entity with key '{Id: 2}'.
info: 9/20/2023 12:15:31.227 RelationalEventId.CommandExecuted[20101] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command) 
      Executed DbCommand (44ms) [Parameters=[@p38='-2147482647', @p39='2', @p40='-2147482646', @p41='3'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      MERGE [ContactTypeXrefs] USING (
      VALUES (@p38, @p39, 0),
      (@p40, @p41, 1)) AS i ([ContactId], [ContactTypeId], _Position) ON 1=0
      WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT ([ContactId], [ContactTypeId])
      VALUES (i.[ContactId], i.[ContactTypeId])
      OUTPUT INSERTED.[Id], INSERTED.[Created], i._Position;
```

#### Working Example

```cs
[Fact]
public void StackOverflow_WorkingExample()
{
    // Arrange
    var carrierContact = new Contact
    {
        Name = "Test Carrier Contact",
        Address1 = "456 Some Street",
        IsActive = true,
    };
    Context.Contacts.Add(carrierContact);
    var carrierContactType = Context.ContactTypes.FirstOrDefault(ct => ct.Id == ContactTypeEnum.Carrier);
    carrierContact.ContactTypes.Add(carrierContactType);

    var vendorContact = new Contact()
    {
        Name = "Test Vendor Contact",
        Address1 = "123 Another Street",
        IsActive = true,
    };
    Context.Contacts.Add(vendorContact);
    var vendorContactType = Context.ContactTypes.FirstOrDefault(ct => ct.Id == ContactTypeEnum.Vendor);
    vendorContact.ContactTypes.Add(vendorContactType);

    Context.SaveChanges();
}
```

#### Thoughts and Troubleshooting

- It appears EF isn't able to connect the `ContactType` and `Contact` records when initialized within the same object. The SQL suggests it's trying to insert a `ContactTypeXref` record with -21474822647 and -21474822646 as the `Contact.Id` field (the defaults), even though the log indicates the Ids were just set to 1 and 2, respectively.
- When the `Contact` objects are initialized with blank `ContactType` properties and then modified later, I suspect the EF tracker is able to keep track and then insert the Xref records accordingly.
- Below is the `ContactTypeConfiguration` class. Perhaps it's missing a field specifically denoted as a key?

```
// ContactType EntityTypeConfiguration
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ContactType> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable(
        TableName, x =>
            x.HasComment(
                "Table representation of ContactTypeEnum for referential integrity. Do not edit without matching change to Enum  in code."));

    builder.Property(x => x.Id)
        .ValueGeneratedNever();

    builder.HasData(
        new List<ContactType>
        {
            new() { Id = ContactTypeEnum.Carrier, Name = "Carrier" },
            new() { Id = ContactTypeEnum.Customer, Name = "Customer" },             new() { Id = ContactTypeEnum.Shipper, Name = "Shipper" },             new() { Id = ContactTypeEnum.Vendor, Name = "Vendor" },
        });
}

// Contact EntityTypeConfiguration
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Contact> builder)
{
    // Primary Key
    builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
    builder.Property(x => x.Id)
        .HasColumnOrder(0);

    // Incices
    builder.HasIndex(x => x.Name);
    builder.HasIndex(x => x.Address1);
    builder.HasIndex(x => x.Address2);
    builder.HasIndex(x => x.Address3);
    builder.HasIndex(x => x.City);
    builder.HasIndex(x => x.State);
    builder.HasIndex(x => x.PostalCode);

    // Auditing
    builder.Property(x => x.Created)
        .HasColumnOrder(1);

    builder.Property(x => x.Modified)
        .HasColumnOrder(2);

    builder.Property(x => x.CreatedBy)
        .HasColumnOrder(3);

    builder.Property(x => x.ModifiedBy)
        .HasColumnOrder(4);

    // Versioning
    builder.Property(x => x.Version)
        .IsRowVersion()
        .HasColumnOrder(5);

    // Soft-delete
    builder.Property(x => x.IsDeleted)
        .HasColumnOrder(6);

    // Property settings
    builder.Property(x => x.IsActive)
        .HasColumnOrder(7);
    // Snip...property mappings

    // Many-to-Many Relationship Between Contacts and ContactTypes
    builder.HasMany(x => x.ContactTypes)
        .WithMany()
        .UsingEntity<ContactTypeXref>(
            ContactTypeXrefTableName,
            l => l.HasOne<ContactType>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.ContactTypeId),
            r => r.HasOne<Contact>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.ContactId),
            z =>
            {
                // Setup payload property
                z.Property(e => e.Created).HasDefaultValueSql(SqlServerSysDatetimeOffset);
            });
}
```

- This is the Xref table, as designed by EF:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "ContactTypeXrefs",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
            .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
        ContactId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
        ContactTypeId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
        Created = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(type: "datetimeoffset", nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()"),
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_ContactTypeXrefs", x => x.Id);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_ContactTypeXrefs_ContactTypes_ContactTypeId",
            column: x => x.ContactTypeId,
            principalTable: "ContactTypes",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_ContactTypeXrefs_Contacts_ContactId",
            column: x => x.ContactId,
            principalTable: "Contacts",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    });
```

Am I missing something or is there no way to initialize a fully-hydrated object all at once in EF?

Comment: You issue is the key is used in more than one table and not all the tables have the attribute KEY on the property.  To fix you have to add the key attribute to id in all tables and then run migration to update the database.  Entity there is a mapping between the c# classes and the database and you need to update the mapping and the database to add the missing primary key attribute.

Comment: Thanks @jdweng, I edited my post to include the `EntityTypeConfiguration`. I see I didn't put a `HasKey` call for the `Id` property. Is this what you meant? After I added `HasKey`, no new SQL was created. But perhaps it'll hint EF on how to behave?